# Alignment of isosceles triangles in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to line up a few isosceles triangles, but I cannot get all of them to align at their top (or bottom) properly. Following is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\tikzstyle{tri} = [draw, isosceles triangle, shape border rotate=-90,inner sep=0pt, minimum width=4em]

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.8cm,>=latex']
    \node [tri] (gain3) {$4$};
    \node [tri,left of=gain3] (gain2) {$3$};
    \node [tri,left of=gain2] (gain1) {$-2$};
    \node [tri,left of=gain1] (gain0) {$1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

And the result is this:
[image: Result: 4 images not properly aligned]

And yes, if the minus sign in front of the 2 is dropped, everything lines up properly. How can this be fixed in an elegant way? (i.e., without putting the contents of the triangle nodes inside an \mbox of predefined size, etc.)

Comment: Add the `shape border uses incircle` option to each triangle.

Answer (score 11):

## Simple solution

Here is a very simple solution (using the `shape border uses incircle` option). But this solution is not robust (try with `$-245$` instead of `$-2$`).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\tikzset{
  tri/.style={
    minimum width=4em,
    draw,
    isosceles triangle,
    shape border uses incircle,
    shape border rotate=-90,
    inner sep=0pt,
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm,>=latex']
    \node [tri] (gain3) {$4$};
    \node [tri,left=of gain3] (gain2) {$3$};
    \node [tri,left=of gain2] (gain1) {$-2$};
    \node [tri,left=of gain1] (gain0) {$1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## General solution

The robust solution no longer uses the `minimum width` option but the `text width` and `align` options.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\tikzset{
  tri width of/.style={
    draw,
    isosceles triangle,
    shape border uses incircle,
    shape border rotate=-90,
    inner sep=0pt,
    align=flush center,text width={width("#1")},
  },
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
    \tikzset{tri2/.style={tri width of=$-2$}}
    \node [tri2] (gain3) {$4$};
    \node [tri2,left=of gain3] (gain2) {$3$};
    \node [tri2,left=of gain2] (gain1) {$-2$};
    \node [tri2,left=of gain1] (gain0) {$1$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
    \tikzset{tri3/.style={tri width of=$-345$}}
    \node [tri3] (gain3) {$4$};
    \node [tri3,left=of gain3] (gain2) {$3$};
    \node [tri3,left=of gain2] (gain1) {$-345$};
    \node [tri3,left=of gain1] (gain0) {$678$ $-345$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Very elegant indeed!! :)

Answer (score 9):

Possibly, the quickest fix is to add `text width=2em,align=center` to the `tri` style, this makes the box containing the text the same width in all cases, which gives the same result.

In the code below I made some other changes as well:

- Changed the deprecated `left of=` to the `left=of` syntax, which requires `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` ([Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386))
- According to the manual, the `arrows` library is also considered deprecated, in favor of `arrows.meta`.
- Finally, `\tikzset{stylename/.style={..}}` is usually recommended over `\tikzstyle`, though I suppose that's mostly a question of preference ([Should `\tikzset` or `\tikzstyle` be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372))

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{
  shapes.geometric,
  arrows.meta, % supersedes arrows
  positioning
}
\tikzset{
 tri/.style={
   draw,
   isosceles triangle,
   shape border rotate=-90,
   inner sep=0pt,
   text width=2em, % added
   align=center,   % added
   minimum width=4em
 }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex]
    \node [tri] (gain3) {$4$};

% alternative, setting anchors explicitly (requires larger node distance)
%    \node [tri,left=of gain3.north, anchor=north] (gain2) {$3$};
%    \node [tri,left=of gain2.north, anchor=north] (gain1) {$-2$};
%    \node [tri,left=of gain1.north, anchor=north] (gain0) {$1$};

    \node [tri,left=of gain3] (gain2) {$3$};
    \node [tri,left=of gain2] (gain1) {$-2$};
    \node [tri,left=of gain1] (gain0) {$1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice. Upvote, also, your answer.

Answer (score 6):

One possibility: use the positioning library and anchors.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\tikzset{tri/.style={draw, isosceles triangle, shape border rotate=-90,inner
sep=0pt, minimum width=4em}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.8cm,>=latex']
    \node [tri] (gain3) {$4$};
    \node [tri,left=of gain3.north,anchor=north] (gain2) {$3$};
    \node [tri,left=of gain2.north,anchor=north] (gain1) {$-2$};
    \node [tri,left=of gain1.north,anchor=north] (gain0) {$1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I upvote your answer. But is it possible align the numbers?

Comment: @Sebastiano This would essentially amount to copying Torbjørn T.'s nice code (which I of course upvoted).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that $-2$ uses more space. Solved with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\tikzstyle{tri} = [draw, isosceles triangle, shape border rotate=-90,inner sep=0pt, minimum width=4em,minimum height= 2cm]
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.8cm,>=latex']
    \node (g4) {$4$};
    \node (g3) [left of= g4] {$3$};
    \node (g2) [left of= g3] {$-2$};
    \node (g1) [left of=g2] {$1$};
    \node [tri] at (g4) {};
    \node [tri] at (g3) {};
    \node [tri] at (g2) {};
    \node [tri] at (g1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

That way, the triangle is seperated from the text.

[image]

Comment: Very nice also your answer. +1.

Comment: I like to first set everthing properly and then add things. Makes it (IMHO) easier to change things later, although it is more work in the beginning.

Comment: This solution should've crossed my mind! I did think about separating text from triangle, but thought I'd end up disconnecting their positions. Stupid me :)

Answer (score 3):

A simple hack with `makebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eqparbox, makebox, mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\tikzstyle{tri} = [draw, isosceles triangle, shape border rotate=-90,inner sep=0pt, minimum width=4em]

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.8cm,>=latex']
    \node [tri] (gain3) {$4$};
    \node [tri,left of=gain3] (gain2) {$3$};
    \node [tri,left of=gain2] (gain1) {\makebox[0.6em]{$-2$}};
    \node [tri,left of=gain1] (gain0) {$1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Vote +1 also your answer. :-) good all answers.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but I explicitly mentioned that I did not want to make use of spacing tweaks using \mbox.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that.